# Why we don't need i++ in File Operation in java?

Tags: java, file

Why don't we need `i++` in the following snippet:

```
import java.io.*;
    class PracIn
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            try
            {
            System.out.println("Reading From File.....\n\n");

            /* You MUST create First File myOwnFile.txt in your machine */
            /* Add some Text on that File */

            FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("myOwnFile.txt");   

            int i=0;

            while((i=fin.read())!=-1)
            {
                System.out.print((char)i);      /* why we don't need i++*/
            }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

What is the theory behind the logic?

Comment: fin.read() fetches next byte from file. As, its reaches to end, it will return -1 as it doesn't have any thing to read, i.e. condition to check for end of file And loops terminates

Answer (score 3):

`i` is not a loop index here, so there's no need to increment it. `i` is assigned each byte being read from the file.

Comment: Thank you for Giving Reply sir !

so how next byte being fetch ?

Comment: @NikhilPatil Each call to `fin.read()` fetches the next byte.

Answer (score 1):

The read() method basically returns the "the next byte of data, or -1 if the end of the file is reached" and it is assigned to i. The while loop is checking the value of i as a conditional statement. So that's why we don't need to increment the value of i (the value of i depends on return value from read () function of FileInputStream). The loop will be ended once the the condition will be true; which means the value of i will be -1 (end of the file reached).

For details clarification, please go through the below link. Here you can find the details of the read() method. Hope this answers your question.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html

Answer (score 1):

this is the code snippet that i have used to read line from file and store it in a string array, hope this will be useful for you :)

```
public class user {
 public static void main(String x[]) throws IOException{
  BufferedReader b=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("<path to file>"));
  String[] user=new String[30];
  String line="";
  while ((line = b.readLine()) != null) {
   user[i]=line; 
   System.out.println(user[1]);
   i++;  
   }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think that you need to do `i++`.

```
int i;
i=fin.read();
```

Here you reading a character at a time. Also, it is not like a pointer in the file that you need to increment each time you read a character. The `read()` method read the character and returns it. When it encounter the end of the file, it will return the `-1`. Because while reading each of the character is returned by their ASCII value, so you need to convert back to `char` and print it.

---

Here is the implementation of `read()` method from `FileInputStream` class. It uses a native implementation for reading the byte from the file.

```
public int read() throws IOException {
    return read0();
}

private native int read0() throws IOException;
```

Further reading about native `read()`: [native read()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29268186/2254048)